# Write .d.ts fie for my own JavaScript file

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I have an application writing in JavaScript and I would like to use TypeScript for a new feature. I have a base class defined in JavaScript, for example.

```
// base.js

module.exports = function BaseClass () {
    // ... ...
};
```

And in my TypeScript I need to create a class from it like this.

```
// sub.ts
import Base from "./base.js";
class Sub extends Base {
    // ... ...
}
```

But I found there is an error in `sub.ts` said

```
Type "Base" is not a constructor function type.
```

I would like to know why this happen? Is this because there's no `.d.ts` file for my `base.js`? If so, how can I create the definitely file for `base.js` and where I need to put this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this because there's no .d.ts file for my base.js?

Yes.

> If so, how can I create the definitely file for base.js

Simply `base.d.ts`:

```
declare class Base {
}
```

> and where I need to put this file?

Next to `base.js`.

Comment: Seems that I also need to put `export = Base;` inside the `.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 1):

A full example, based on @basarat's answer:

```
// data.js
var data = {
  "values": [
    {
      "value": "a",
    },
    {
      "value": "b",
    }
  ],
  "year" : 2018
  }

export { data }
```

```
export declare class data {
    static values : any[];
    static year   : number
}
```

```
// app.ts
import { data } from './data.js';

// data.values.filter() // autocompletion for Array methods should appear in the IDE
// data.year.toFixed(1) // // autocompletion for Number methods should appear in the IDE
```

Tested in a Angular 6 application with: TypeScript V2.9.2.